# Cómo puedo agregar un checkbox en mi JTable en Java?

Tags: java, mysql

Tengo un JTable el cual puedes elegir un usuario haciendo 1 clic pero, vi un ejemplo de un JTable con checkbox, el cual puedes marcar los que quieras y es mucho mejor.

Me he guiado de un ejemplo que he visto pero, no me funciona.

Código de mi table:

```
Globalmente: private JTable tableInvitados;

JScrollPane scrollPaneInvitados = new JScrollPane();
        scrollPaneInvitados.setBounds(10, 41, 288, 168);
        JPanelCreacionDeInvitaciones.add(scrollPaneInvitados);

        tableInvitados = new JTable();
        tableInvitados.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
                // Obtener la fila seleccionada
                for (int i = 0; i < tableInvitados.getRowCount(); i++) {
                    Boolean checked = Boolean.valueOf(tableInvitados.getValueAt(i, 0).toString());
                    String col = tableInvitados.getValueAt(i, 1).toString();
                }
            }
        });
        scrollPaneInvitados.setViewportView(tableInvitados);
```

En otra clase tengo el DefaultTableModel:

```
public DefaultTableModel tableRegistrosInvitados() {
        DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel() {

            public Class<?> getColumnClass(int column) {
                switch(column) {
                case 0:
                    return String.class;
                case 1:
                    return String.class;
                case 2:
                    return String.class;
                case 3:
                    return String.class;
                case 4:
                    return Boolean.class;
                default:
                    return String.class;
                }
            }
        };

        sSQL = "SELECT * FROM invitado ORDER BY id_invitado";

        // Java 7 try-with-resources
        try (Statement st = con.createStatement();
             ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(sSQL)) {

            String [] titulosColumnas = {"ID", "Nombre", "Apellido", "Sexo", "?"};
            rs.last();
            int filas = rs.getRow();
            rs.first();
            Object [][] registros = new Object[filas][titulosColumnas.length]; 

            int i = 0;
            do {
                registros[i][0] = rs.getInt("id_invitado");
                registros[i][1] = rs.getString("nombre");
                registros[i][2] = rs.getString("apellido");
                registros[i][3] = rs.getString("sexo");
                registros[i][4] = false;
                i++;
            } while (rs.next());

            model = new DefaultTableModel(registros, titulosColumnas);

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "SQLException:\n" + e, "Error: Logica_invitaciones.tableRegistrosInvitados()", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            }

        return model;
    }
```

Resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Qué estoy haciendo mal?, es mi primera vez tratando de hacer esto.

El fin es poder seleccionar los invitados que quieras, obtener el ID de los invitados en un Array para luego, guardarlos todos en la base de datos.

Espero puedan ayudarme.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Estás poniendo código innecesario. Cambia el código cuando cargas la tabla por esto:

```
model = new DefaultTableModel(registros, titulosColumnas){
    public Class<?> getColumnClass(int column) {
        if(column == 0) return Integer.class;
        else if(column == 4) return Boolean.class;
        else return String.class;
    }
};
```

Comment: vale, funciona. Una cosa, en los parametros me dice: The serializable class  does not declare a static final serialVersionUID field of type long, a qué se debo esto?, es necesario agregarle un serialVersionUID ?, de ser así, cuál es mejor?, default o generated?.

Comment: Yo siempre pongo el @SuppresWarning. Nunca uso eso.

Comment: al hacer estos cambios, veo que la columna ID se ha alineado a mano derecha, por qué?, screenshot: https://s4.postimg.org/r7qddi399/Screenshot_251.png

Comment: Porque ahora devuelve que la clase que hay en esa columna del model es un entero y el render para los números lo pone así. Si no quieres que sea así ponle que lo devuelva como en String o puedes ponerle un render hecho por tí. Los [Cell Render](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableCellRenderer.html) son una herramienta muy poderosa pudiendo darle a la celda un formato concreto en el que quieres que muestre la información (imagina que sólo quieres dos decimales, añadir un símbolo de moneda al final o ponerlo en rojo y  con negrita se es un número negativo, etc...)

Comment: vale, una ultima cosa, estoy tratando de obtener el ID de la fila con el checkbox seleccionado, debo guardar esos ID para luego enviarselo a una funcion para guardarlos en la base de datos pero, el codigo para obtener el ID de la seleccion, no me sale. Cheka: http://pastie.org/private/uyp42w5vr24eetgocdts5a

Comment: Para eso mejor abre otra pregunta poniendo muy claro qué tendría que hacer el usuario, cómo tendría que comportarse la aplicación y preguntando dónde tienes problemas en tu código que has intentado.